# NetBeans Platform Application - change Icon generated by Installer

Tags: java, swing, icons, netbeans-platform, branding

I developed an NetBeans Platform Application and generated a Windows installer. When I install the application I have the following Icon on the desktop:

[image]

Where do I change the icon in the settings of the project? In the branding of my NetBeans project, I changed all 3 application icons to my icon, but still I end up with the one above on the desktop.

Comment: I also think it is really an issue that this icon can not be defined during maven build.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you changed the icon for /build/launcher/bin/.exe file.

This is most likely being overwritten with the default.

You can manually change the icon for the default executable here:
/harness/launchers/app.exe

Checkout http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqExecutableIcon

The docs here say you can use a third-party tool - but i have never tried this.

Answer (score -1):

padde's answer on [How to change icon on mavenized netbeans project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25302132/18356) is to

- Applying changes with ReplaceVistaIcon on app.exe and app64.exe(more explanation can be found on [How to change icon on Netbeans Project](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/icons_for_netbeans_platform_applications)), I only needed to copy app.exe and app64.exe from "NetBeans\harness\launchers\" into "src\main\resources\"

Then in your pom.xml :

`<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <brandingToken>${brandingToken}</brandingToken>
                <etcConfFile>src/main/resources/myconfig.conf</etcConfFile>
                <binDirectory>src/main/resources/binaries</binDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>`

I noticed that app.exe and app64.exe are different in size from NetBeans 7.3 and 7.3.1. But matches between 7.3.1 and 8.0.2. I believe that we should use the app.exe from NetBeans version that is matching with our project's NetBeans version.